# Padding on progressbar drawable is not applied

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I have this drawable for my progressbar:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background"  android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="@color/gray11"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="@color/gray11"
            android:startColor="@color/gray11" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"  android:top="5dp">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="@color/blue1"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/blue1"
                android:startColor="@color/blue1" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:top="5dp">

    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/blue1"
                android:startColor="@color/blue1" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

I want to shift the drawable downwards so I added android:top="5dp" but the padding (downward shift) is not applied and I can't get why.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably way too late, but I am posting this here for anyone who has this problem in the future and stumbles upon this question.

Before Marshmallow, there was a bug where certain properties put on the children of a `LayerDrawable` were disregarded when that `LayerDrawable` was used as a progress drawable. The bug was actually in `ProgressBar`, where the value of `android:progressDrawable` would run through a `tileify` method, which would re-generate the `LayerDrawable` but would fail to copy certain properties (most notably the paddings).

You can see the fix for this in AOSP [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6a8253f).

The easiest workaround for this issue is to call `setProgressDrawable` from code instead of supplying `android:progressDrawable`. Because `setProgressDrawable` doesn't call `tileify` (and because `tileify` might as well be a no-op anyway for all cases where there is no `BitmapDrawable`), you'll keep your paddings and other properties.

Note, however, that if your progress drawable contains `bitmap`/`BitmapDrawable`, you may need to implement part of `tileify` yourself to make sure you're getting the same tiling behavior as from xml (or, on Lollipop and above, you can call `setProgressDrawableTiled`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly! Remenber not put android:progressDrawable in xml because setProgressDrawable() not will have effect

Answer (score 0):

The padding property is not taken into account for < item > tag. It's simply not parsing or including it, since it makes little sense to do it there.

Properly set padding should be included as child in your < shape > tag like this:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <padding 
                android:top="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/blue1"
                android:startColor="@color/blue1" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```